# What is the maximum number of rows from a left join

Tags: mysql, join

What is the maximum number of rows from a left join from the below query?

```
select t1.tribe_name, t2.*
from tribe_master as t1
left join demography as t2
on t1.stc_code=t2.stc_code
```

In the above query table **tribe_master** has total 868 records
and table demography has 16924 records,
but the output of the query shows 14,899  records.
How is this possible.
Please explain.

Comment: There is nothing at all unexpected about the current size of the result set, assuming that data supports it.  Perhaps you are confounding a _cross_ join, which would result in `868 x 16924` records, with a _left_ join, which only join two records if the `ON` clause criteria are met.

Comment: How often do you use `LEFT JOIN` and what do you expect it to do based from your understanding?

Comment: 'What is the maximum number of rows from a left join' - it depends on how many duplicates (based on stc_code) there are in both tables..

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have two tables, A & B and both tables have each id of 1 & 2 like below. When you use `A.id=B.id` you'll get two matches:

```
Ex1:
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 1 id UNION SELECT 2) A LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 1 id UNION SELECT 2) B ON A.id=B.id;
+----+----+
| id | id |
+----+----+
| 1  |  1 |
| 2  |  2 |
+----+----+
*2 row(s);
```

If table A only have id 1 and table B have id 1 & 2, result will show only 1 match:

```
Ex2:
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 1 id) A LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 1 id UNION SELECT 2) B ON A.id=B.id;
+----+----+
| id | id |
+----+----+
| 1  |  1 |
+----+----+
*1 row(s);
```

If table A have id 1 & 2 and table B only have id 1, you'll get 2 rows of result regardless of how many matching id there is. However in the id section from table B, you'll only get data for whatever matches and get `NULL` for non-matching data.

```
Ex3:
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 1 id UNION SELECT 2) A LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 1 id) B ON A.id=B.id;
+----+---------+
| id |    id   |
+----+---------+
| 1  |    1    |
| 2  |  (NULL) |
+----+---------+
*2 row(s);
```

When you have id 1 & 2 in table A and duplicate id 2 in table B, you'll get 3 rows since id 2 from table A matches with two rows if id 2 data in table B. And of course, `NULL` for non-matching data.

```
Ex4:
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 1 id UNION SELECT 2) A LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 2 id UNION ALL SELECT 2) B ON A.id=B.id;
+----+---------+
| id |    id   |
+----+---------+
| 1  |  (NULL) |
| 2  |    2    |
| 2  |    2    |
+----+---------+
*3 row(s);
```

Then the last test here showing both tables have two rows of duplicate id 1 which resulted in 4 total rows because each of the id 1 row in table A recognizes that there are two matching id in table B

```
Ex5:
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 1 id UNION ALL SELECT 1) A LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 1 id UNION ALL SELECT 1) B ON A.id=B.id;
+----+----+
| id | id |
+----+----+
| 1  |  1 |
| 1  |  1 |
| 1  |  1 |
| 1  |  1 |
+----+----+
*4 row(s);
```

Yours probably have a few data in table `tribe_master` that don't exists in table `demography` and some repeated `stc_code` values in the `demography`. Something like `Ex4` example above.